# How to access text string in groupBy result?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using _.groupBy to group an array of objects.   The groupBy works fine, resulting in the following format:

```js
Object {
     Category A: Array[3], 
     Category B: Array[2]
}
```

The problem I'm having is accessing the category name text from the resulting object, e.g. "Category A" and "Category B".  I don't know these in advance so I need to be able to access the text itself.

Here's a JSFiddle with an example: [JS Fiddle with groupBy example](https://jsfiddle.net/wrefykn2/)

How can I access the group name text?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use `Object.keys()` or `_.keys()` in order to get the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate through the object and get the name, as:

```
for(prop in resultObj) {
    console.log(prop); //this gives you 'Category A', 'Category B'
}
```

or use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get key's as array:

```
var keys = Object.keys(yourObject); //returns array of keys
console.log(keys);
```